# Pinescript IF Statement Array

Tags: arrays, if-statement, pine-script

Hi i am struggling to get my array in Pinescript to produce anything other than a list of Nan. I am trying to create an array of the % difference of the low and 20sma when price bounces off the 20sma but currently when i print the array it only has Nan values.

```
sma_20 = sma(close,20)
sma_20_touch_band = open>sma_20 and low<=sma_20
sma_20_dif = ((low-sma_20)/sma_20)
sma_20_array = array.new_float(100)

if sma_20_touch_band
    array.push(sma_20_array, sma_20_dif)
    array.shift(sma_20_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely caused by not using a `var` array. Without the `var` keyword, your array will be re-initialized on each bar. You need to initialze your array once, and manipulate its elements later on. Therefore make it:

```
var sma_20_array = array.new_float(100)
```

Also, I'm not so sure about your usage of the `array.shift()` function.

You push something to the array, but with the `array.shift()` you remove the first element from the array. At the end of the day, you remove what you have just added. At least this is what I think is happening.